# How to execute .htaccess script based on local machine or live?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want my htaccess code to work only on my live machine and not the local,
What code can I write in the HTaccess to differentiate?

Comment: Delete the `.htaccess` file from the local machine, or rename it.

Comment: The question lacks of information. What's live achine and what's local? How do you suppose to run `htaccess`?

Comment: @J0HN I think he meant online website by live machine  and local host by local! and by running htaccess he meant set different rules base on if it's online website or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your local apache VirtualHost add this instruction:

```
<Directory /my/directory/where/the/htaccess/is >
    # prevent reads of .htaccess files
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Then you local Apache will never read any .htaccess in this directory (and subdirectories)

Comment: Sorry but thats nbot what I need, theres one code to be executed on the local version and one htaccess on the live, so I cant disable htaccess.

Comment: everything you was used to put in a .htaccess can be safely put in the Directory instruction in the apache conf. .htaccess is just a slow hack to put apache configuration on hosted env. So for your local version put everything in the apache configuration Directory section.

Comment: depends of your OS, and distribution. For Debian it's in /etc/apache2/sites-[available|enabled], could be in conf.d subdir as well, checl your distribution apache docs